# C++ caching/storing items with different data types

Tags: c++

What is generally the best practice to store values that are computation heavy. I initially only calculated doubles and used a map to store them

```
class Calc
{
    map<string, double> m_cache;
    virtual bool isCached(const string& key )
              { return m_cache.find(key) != m_cache_.end(); }

    double getHeavyA() { 
        string key = "a";
        if ( !isCached( key ) ) { m_cache[key] = getHeavyA(); }
        return m_cache[key];
    }

    double getHeavyB() { 
        string key = "b";
        if ( !isCached( key ) ) { m_cache[key] = getHeavyB(); }
        return m_cache[key];
    }

    void clearCache() { m_cache.clear(); }
```

probably not the most elegant and efficient way in itself. But now I have also functions returning different obj/data types and I would rather avoid having various maps with one for each data type. Is there a preferred way to do it? I can only come up with a struct that holds the different values. Is that a good approach or is there better way?

Comment: BTW, You currently do 3 lookup whereas only one is enough.

Comment: I see how I can do two, but one? can I check and replace at the same time?

Comment: `std::map::insert` returns a pair *iterator/inserted*. So by inserting dummy value, you may check if you have to update value (with iterator), or directly use it.

Comment: `boost::optional` seems more appropriate that `std::map`, as your key seems dummy.

Comment: @Jarod. you mean something like this
std::pair<std::map<char,int>::iterator,bool> ret;
 ret = mymap.insert ( std::pair<char,int>('z',500) );
So, If I insert a dummy value, wouldnt I set that maps value to the dummy and by the next time I check if the item is there get a wrong value?

Comment: Not allowed to use boost

Comment: `std::unqiue_ptr` is an easy replacement of `boost::optional`

Comment: How would unique pointers help me here?

Comment: For the map, something like [That](http://ideone.com/mBmWaE).

Comment: ah, thanks. now I understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a `map` if you don't need to!

```
template<typename T>
struct Cached {
  T value_;
  bool valid_= false;
  void Update(T x) { value_ = x; valid_ = true;}
  void Uncache() { valid_ = false;}
};

class Calc {
    Cached<double> a_;
    double getA() {
        // don't be tempted to merge this into a call. You don't want to 
        // call getHeavyA() unnecessarily.
        if ( !a.Valid_ ) { a_.Update( getHeavyA()); }
        return a_.value_;
    }

    Cached<int64_t> b_;    
    int64_t getB() { 
        if ( !b.Valid_ ) { b_.Update( getHeavyB()); }
        return b_.value_;
    }

    ...

   void clearCache() { a_.Uncache(); b_.Uncache(); }
```

Comment: You may even take the heavy functor in argument of cached to factorized the getter logic.

Comment: Thanks. I like the approach. My main reason to use a central container was that it is easy to clear and make sure all cached values are cleared by making sure they are in the map. So when more functions, values gets added, they do not have to also be added to clearCache. Is there a magic way to add that feature to your approach? I don't see how, but then again... I don't know much about the magic and possibilities of c++

Comment: There is a way to fix that. You need to make a container that contains all cached object, and when you construct each Cached<x> object, you give a reference to the container, so the container knows about it. Then the container has a method that calls `Uncache()` on each element.